# How to calculate fibonacci function by math formula

Tags: javascript, math

How to calculate fibonacci function by math formula

I have try this formula but not work:

```
fib(n) = ((1 + 5^0.5) / 2)^n - ((1 - 5^0.5) / 2)^n / 5^0.5

const fib=(n)=>{
    return ((1+(5**0.5))/2)**n-((1-(5**0.5))/2)**n/(5**0.5)
}
```

Any one know how to do?Thanks.

Comment: None of [*these*](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+fibonacci+function) do it for you?

Comment: You could start by breaking out φ into a separate variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula is correct you just need to put some extra `()`.

```js
const fib=(n)=>{
    return (((1+(5**0.5))/2)**n-(((1-(5**0.5))/2)**n))/(5**0.5)
}
for(let i = 0;i<9;i++){
  console.log(fib(i))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be trying to recreate *Binet's Formula*. You can break down the formula a little like so, such that is becomes more readable:

```js
const fib = n => {
  const alpha = 5**0.5
  const beta = alpha / 2;
  return (1 / alpha) * ((0.5 + beta) ** n - (0.5 - beta) ** n);
}

console.log(fib(10));
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing I'd do is define φ

```
var φ = (1 + 5 ** 0.5) / 2;
```

Then a slightly shorter form is:

```
var fib = (n) => (φ ** n - ((-φ) ** -n)) / (2 * φ - 1);
```

Because you want an integer as a result, you could also throw in the call to `Math.round()`.